ROS2 Humble With ASAN
I'm attempting to integrate ROS into some existing software.   When I build with ASAN, which is part of our CI/CD infrastructure, I get an error that seems to originate within librcl.
Is this a result of a configuration error, or is there a way to mitigate the issue so it doesn't fail our builds and unit tests?
We are running the ROS2 Humble  (Relevant RHEL8 RPMs: ros-humble-ros-base-0.10.0-1.el8.20240830.202601.x86_64, ros-humble-rclcpp-16.0.10-1.el8.20240728.223031.x86_64)
==13468==ERROR: AddressSanitizer: new-delete-type-mismatch on 0x50700000d220 in thread T0:       
  object passed to delete has wrong type: 
  size of the allocated type:   72 bytes;
  size of the deallocated type: 1 bytes.
    #0 0x7f91461aa018 in operator delete(void*, unsigned long) (/lib64/libasan.so.8+0xfc018) (BuildId: 98bb16229beb4f63e6e54817a90d0e80fe9febf6)
    #1 0x47f966 in std::__new_allocator<char>::deallocate(char*, unsigned long) /opt/rh/gcc-toolset-13/root/usr/include/c++/13/bits/new_allocator.h:172
    #2 0x4c181c in std::allocator<char>::deallocate(char*, unsigned long) /opt/rh/gcc-toolset-13/root/usr/include/c++/13/bits/allocator.h:210
    #3 0x4c181c in std::allocator_traits<std::allocator<char> >::deallocate(std::allocator<char>&, char*, unsigned long) /opt/rh/gcc-toolset-13/root/usr/include/c++/13/bits/alloc_traits.h:517
    #4 0x4c181c in void rclcpp::allocator::retyped_deallocate<char, std::allocator<char> >(void*, void*) /opt/ros/humble/include/rclcpp/rclcpp/allocator/allocator_common.hpp:67
    #5 0x7f913d75549e in rcutils_string_map_fini (/opt/ros/humble/lib/librcutils.so+0xe49e) (BuildId: 418a08a407e0afcbf4ad0065e0678b11b7812d48)                                                   #6 0x7f914425f375 in rcl_resolve_name (/opt/ros/humble/lib/librcl.so+0x21375) (BuildId: 7edb420ca655849e73979715d5332969a03dda29)
    #7 0x7f914425f6c7 in rcl_node_resolve_name (/opt/ros/humble/lib/librcl.so+0x216c7) (BuildId: 7edb420ca655849e73979715d5332969a03dda29)
    #8 0x7f914425c928 in rcl_publisher_init (/opt/ros/humble/lib/librcl.so+0x1e928) (BuildId: 7edb420ca655849e73979715d5332969a03dda29)
    #9 0x7f9144874d7f in rclcpp::PublisherBase::PublisherBase(rclcpp::node_interfaces::NodeBaseInterface*, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, rosidl_message_type_support_t const&, rcl_publisher_options_s const&) (/opt/ros/humble/lib/librclcpp.so+0x1eed7f) (BuildId: 6eec2d4e0a9d014cf1f30b4a88c3aafbd8b3cc36)
    #10 0x7f914482073e in rclcpp::Publisher<rcl_interfaces::msg::ParameterEvent_<std::allocator<void> >, std::allocator<void> >::Publisher(rclcpp::node_interfaces::NodeBaseInterface*, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, rclcpp::QoS const&, rclcpp::PublisherOptionsWithAllocator<std::allocator<void> > const&) (/opt/ros/humble/lib/librclcpp.so+0x19a73e) (BuildId: 6eec2d4e0a9d014cf1f30b4a88c3aafbd8b3cc36)
    #11 0x7f9144821df8 in std::_Function_handler<std::shared_ptr<rclcpp::PublisherBase> (rclcpp::node_interfaces::NodeBaseInterface*, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, rclcpp::QoS const&), rclcpp::create_publisher_factory<rcl_interfaces::msg::ParameterEvent_<std::allocator<void> >, std::allocator<void>, rclcpp::Publisher<rcl_interfaces::msg::ParameterEvent_<std::allocator<void> >, std::allocator<void> > >(rclcpp::PublisherOptionsWithAllocator<std::allocator<void> > const&)::{lambda(rclcpp::node_interfaces::NodeBaseInterface*, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, rclcpp::QoS const&)#1}>::_M_invoke(std::_Any_data const&, rclcpp::node_interfaces::NodeBaseInterface*&&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, rclcpp::QoS const&) (/opt/ros/humble/lib/librclcpp.so+0x19bdf8) (BuildId: 6eec2d4e0a9d014cf1f30b4a88c3aafbd8b3cc36)
    #12 0x7f9144824060 in rclcpp::node_interfaces::NodeTopics::create_publisher(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, rclcpp::PublisherFactory const&, rclcpp::QoS const&) (/opt/ros/humble/lib/librclcpp.so+0x19e060) (BuildId: 6eec2d4e0a9d014cf1f30b4a88c3aafbd8b3cc36)

